# Narrator won't turn off despite everything

Tags: narrator

The Narrator on my computer (Windows 7 version) turned on somehow and won't turn off. I have already been to the Ease of Accessibility section and unticked all the options that tell it to use the Narrator, and I have tried the Windows + Enter shortcuct . . . nothing works.

Comment: I added that Win/U is the on-switch to the other post, as a comment. i first discovered it on Win XP trying to shut the machine down & being just a bit quick with Win, U, U

Answer (score 3):

Pressing  <kbd>Windows</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>  will switch on Narrator… but it won't switch the darned thing off again.

To switch off -

Go to Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Explore all Settings -> Use the computer without a display.
Uncheck the checkbox by 'Turn on Narrator' and click Apply.